# Why function cannot access vector variable declared before?

Tags: python, arrays, variables, syntax

I want my program to spit out a vector whose entries are the average of the entries with same place index of other vectors. The entries of the latter vectors are updated in a `for` loop, thus in the same `for` loop i do the vector sum and in the end I divide by the number of iterations:

```
N=10000
path=np.zeros(N)
path_avg=path
def avg_path_finder(iterations):
    for i in range(iterations):
        index=int(random()*N)
        path[index]+=1
        path_avg+=path
    path_avg=path_avg/iterations
    return path_avg
```

This is the syntax error I get: `Unresolved reference to path_avg`.
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: That's not a syntax error.

Comment: You need `global path_avg` in the function.